# Canvas Image not rendering in Chrome (works in FF4 & IE9)

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I'm stumped. For the life of me, i have no idea why this is not working in Chrome. You can see the code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/corydorning/NgXSH/

When i pull this code up in FF or IE9 it works great. You'll notice that the fiddle WILL work in Chrome with the rendered  element, but it DOES NOT work outside of fiddle.

Any help is greatly appreciated. This is my first attempt with canvas.

Comment: it seems to be working in chrome fore me? am i supposed be seeing the google logo?

Comment: it works intermittently b/c of the image loading. you were lucky. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you're not waiting for the original image element to get loaded.  If you change it around a little, it works fine:

```
  $(function() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    canvasExists = !!(canvas.getContext && canvas.getContext('2d')),
    oImage = $('img')[0];

    if (canvasExists) {
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d'), img = new Image();

      img.onload = function() {
        canvas.height = img.height;
        canvas.width = img.width;

        $(oImage).replaceWith(canvas);

        context.drawImage(oImage, 0, 0);
      }

      img.src = oImage.src; 
    } else {
      // apply MS filters
    }
```

Comment: awesome! works great! Out of curiosity, why do i have to create a new image and set the src to the original image vs. just using the existing image?

Comment: Well you could put a "load" handler on the `<img>` element I guess - I just wrote it that way out of habit.  The point is that you want to wait until the browser thinks it's got its hands on the image before trying to get the width/height (and the actual pixels of course :-)

Answer (score 0):

It could be hard to use img.onload if you have plenty of them. An easy way in chrome to wait for image loading is to use :

```
$(window).load(function () {
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

as $(window).load is actually waiting for all image to be loaded.

It's work perfecly for using the image in the canvas.
(work also in firefow and IE)