# JS - Canvas Image in not working well in chrome ( or how to wait for an image to load properly )

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, canvas

I have a script that draws a QR code with an Image on canvas .

It is using a plugin, and normally - everything works great - but not in chrome .

HTML

```
<img id="#o99-qrs-img-buffer" src="http://localhost/www.beta.com/logo1.png" 
    style="display:none">
<div id="o99_qrcode" class="code"></div>
```

JS script is as follows ( ignore the PHP part - it is working great ):

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var options = {
        render: "'.$qr_render.'", // Canvas, Div ,Image 
        size: '.$qr_size.',
        radius: '.  ($qr_corner_r * 0.1) .',

        .... tons of other options....

        // Image Label -> the problem is here 
        image: jQuery("#o99-qrs-img-buffer")[0], // taken as example
    };

    jQuery("#o99_qrcode").empty().qrcode(options);
});
```

Like said , it is working great on all tested browsers - except in chrome - where it works sporadically . more fail than work. ( 90% - 10% )

Observing a bit , I have noticed two things :

1 - The `jQuery(document).ready(function()` is not really working as form my understaning of what it should be doing ( and my understanding might be wrong of course ) because the script is firing and displaying the image BEFORE the document is finished to load.

2 - I assume by observing that the script fails becuase ( related to 1 ) - the image is actually nowhere to be found when the script fires - so it has nowhere to take the source from ..

At the beginning I blamed the `"display:none"` and changed the div to `style="width:100px;height:100px;"` with  `jQuery("#o99-qrs-img-buffer").hide();` after the script firing .

No good .

then I tried to change the `jQuery(document).ready` to `load` and `onLoad`.

Still no go .

Reading a LOT of related question here on SE - I found 3 with the hint of my problem : [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807116/canvas-image-not-rendering-in-chrome-works-in-ff4-ie9), [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820209/image-onload-event-not-working-in-chrome) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060751/canvas-not-drawing-images).

So I tried to implement the first one , which looked like a solid solution :

```
var imagetest = new Image();

imagetest.onload = function() { 
    // wrap the firing in a function only when the image loads
    jQuery("#o99_qrcode").empty().qrcode(options);
};
imagetest.src: jQuery("#o99-qrs-img-buffer")[0]; // taken as example
```

But chrome seems a lot more persistent than me ...

Either I am implementing the solution totally wrong ( very possible ) or I am so unfamiliar with JS that I do not understand the problem at the first place .

The fact that the script working with a plugin seems irrelevant because the plugin works great on all browsers (and sometimes chrome too ..)

At any rate , I need help In **finding a way to load the Image and be sure it is loaded before the script fires ...**

Comment: `$(document).ready()` is fired when the `body` of the page has been _parsed_. Other resources, like content of `iframe`s and `img`s might still be loading. Use `$(window).load()`, which fires after the whole page is ready and all resources are fully loaded.

Comment: can you use chrome developer tools and check if there is any error in console whenever the output is unexpected.

Comment: @uditbansal - Of course I used the devtools in chrome ( and FF.. ) But apparently there is no error in the console.

Comment: @Teemu - Genius ! It seems to work now. I am not sure if this is from cache or not ( cleaned ) but for now it seems ok. One question though. Should I wrap the whole `options` var in the `$(window).load` or separate only the actual firing ? and also - why `$(document).load` and `$(document).onLoad` failed ?

Comment: Looks like `document` never triggers `load` event, `$(document).onLoad()` doesn't exist. About wrapping, I don't know, use the code which best works for you.

Comment: @Teemu - Thanks . Please Add it as an answer . I will accept it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) is fired, when DOM is fully loaded. In practice this happens at the time when parser have just met `</body>`. This doesn't mean that the page would be ready/fully loaded, content of external resources like `iframe`s or `img` might still be loading. `$(document).ready()` only guarantees you can refer all elements within the HTML.

If you want to wait untill the whole page and all its resources have been completely loaded, you need to use [`$(window).load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/).

Also looks like `document` never triggers `load` event, `$(document).onLoad()` doesn't exist.